# Trying to access an object that is being destroyed

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, c++14

I have an object which contains a thread which indirectly accesses this object like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>

class A;

class Manager
{
public:
    Manager(void) = default;
    void StartA(void)
    {
        a = std::make_unique<A>(*this);
    }
    void StopA(void)
    {
        a = nullptr;
    }
    A& GetA(void)
    {
        return *a;
    }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<A> a;
};

class A
{
public:
    A(Manager& manager)
        : manager{manager},
        shouldwork{true},
        thread{[&]{ this->Run(); }}
    {
    }
    ~A(void)
    {
        shouldwork = false;
        thread.join();
    }
private:
    Manager& manager;
    std::atomic<bool> shouldwork;
    std::thread thread;
    void Run(void)
    {
        while (shouldwork)
        {
            // Here goes a lot of code which calls manager.GetA().
            auto& a = manager.GetA();
        }
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
try
{
    Manager man;
    man.StartA();
    man.StopA();
}
catch (std::exception& e)
{
    std::cerr << "Exception caught: " << e.what() << '\n';
}
catch (...)
{
    std::cerr << "Unknown exception.\n";
}
```

The problem is that when one thread calls `Manager::StopA` and enters destructor of `A`, the thread inside `A` segfaults at `Manager::GetA`. How can I fix this?

Comment: You will get a segmentation fault because you try to dereference a `nullptr`. Calling StopA will set `a` to `nullptr`. GetA dereferences it `return *a`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `StopA()` you set `a = nullptr;`, this in turn destroys the `a` object and all further access to its members result in undefined behaviour (a likely cause the segmentation fault).

Simply moving the `a = nullptr;` to the destructor of the `Manager` could resolve this problem. Even better, allow the RAII mechanism of the `std::unique_ptr` to destroy the `a` object when the destructor of the `Manager` runs (i.e. remove the line of code completely).

With [active object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_object) [implementations](http://www.patterns.pl/activeobject.html), careful control of the member variables is important, especially the "stop variable/control" (here the `shouldwork = false;`). Allow the manager to access the variable directly or via a method to stop the active object before its destruction.

---

Some of the code here looks out of place or obscure, e.g. `a = std::make_unique<A>(*this);`. A redesign could help simplify some of the code. The `Manager` class could be removed.

```
class A
{
public:
    A(): shouldwork{true}, thread{[&]{ this->Run(); }}
    {
    }
    void StopA()
    {
        shouldwork = false;
        thread.join(); 
    }
private:
    std::atomic<bool> shouldwork;
    std::thread thread;
    void Run(void)
    {
        while (shouldwork)
        {
            // code...
        }
    }
};
```

The code is modelled along the lines of `std::thread`, were the stopping of the tread is more controlled before an attempt is made to join it. The destructor is left empty in this case, to mimic the termination (calling `std::terminate`) result, as is the case with the standard thread library. Threads must be explicitly joined (or detached) before destruction.

Re-introducing the `Manager`, the code could look as follows;

```
class A
{
public:
    A() : shouldwork{true}, thread{[&]{ this->Run(); }} {}
    void StopA() { shouldwork = false; thread.join(); }
private:
    void Run();
    std::atomic<bool> shouldwork;
    std::thread thread;
};

class Manager
{
public:
    Manager() = default;
    void StartA(void)
    {
        a = std::make_unique<A>();
    }
    void StopA(void)
    {
        a->StopA();
    }
    A& GetA(void)
    {
        return *a;
    }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<A> a;
};

void A::Run()
{
    while (shouldwork)
    {
        // Here goes a lot of code which calls manager.GetA().
        auto& a = manager.GetA();
    }
}
```

And your `main` remains as it is.

Comment: Ok, I'm trying to apply your fix, unfortunately the real code is a bit more complicated and now I get exception in `thread.join()`, I will update the question if I'll need more help.

Comment: @FaTony. Ok, that could be that it is no longer `joinable()`, which means something else has already joined it, or it has been detached. Watch out for the thread being moved and you joining on an object that no longer represents that thread.

Comment: Ok now I still get segfault at `GetA` while the other thread is in `A` constructor.

Comment: Ok I fixed it by moving thread start code into a separate `Start` function.